# How to convert this form to parametric form?

Tags: linear-algebra

A practice problem [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/psafronov/m408dfiles/mar06.pdf) presents a line as

$\frac{x-2}{3} = \frac{y-1}{5} = \frac{z + 1}{2} $

I've never seen lines written in this form. How do I convert it to the familiar form of

$\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\frac{x-2}{3} = \frac{y-1}{5} = \frac{z + 1}{2}=t$$

Now write $x,y,z$ in terms of $t$

$$x=3t+2$$
$$y=5t+1$$
$$x=2t-1$$

and then write in parametric form

> $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

So each of those is equal to $t$. i.e. we have that $t= \frac{x-2}{3} = \frac{y-1}{5}=\frac{z+1}{2}$. So then solve for $x,y,z$.

$x = 3t+2$, etc. Then you can write your equation of the line in the familiar form.